# What is the opposite of "to bring down the temperature"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

> [to bring down](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bring+down): To reduce the amount or level of something:
>
> I opened the window to bring down the temperature in my room.
>
> Can you bring the volume of the stereo down a bit?

I know that "**to increase**" or "**to raise**" is the opposite of "**to bring down**".

But, the opposite of "**bring**" is "**take**" and the opposite of "**down**" is "**up**".

Do we have "**to take up**" as the opposite of "**to bring down**"?

For example,  I closed the window to take up the temperature in my room.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, "Raise the temperature."

Comment: I would be more likely to speak of  lowering the temperature, but to speak of bringing it down is perfectly correct, too.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the phrase "heat up", for e.g. "to heat up the room, to warm up the car".